# GWT Button remains disabled after dialog box is closed

Tags: java, gwt

I have a button that decorates user ClickHandler with my one which controls button state -> makes it disabled on click preventing multiple clicks. When user clicks on it - corresponding DialogBox is opened and button becomes disabled. Here is my button:

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    private boolean isButtonClicked = false;
    private ClickHandler clickHandler;

    public MyButton(String html) {
        this(html, null);
    }

    public MyButton(String html, final ClickHandler handler) {
        super(html);
        addClickHandler(handler);
    }

    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(final ClickHandler handler) {
        clickHandler = handler;

        ClickHandler ch = new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if(!isButtonClicked) {
                    isButtonClicked = true;
                    setEnabled(false);
                    clickHandler.onClick(event); //Here is a click handler initiated on fly
                }
            }
        };
        return super.addClickHandler(ch);
    }
}
```

And this is how it is used:

```
public TestClass {
    protected OneClickButton button = new OneClickButton("Test Button);

    //...

    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                SomeDialogWindow dialog = new SomeDialogWindow(/*args*/);
                dialog.center();
            }
        });
}
```

When I click on a button it becomes disabled and dialog appears. But when I close the dialog, my button remains disabled. How to set button enable back on dialog close? What event and where should I handle on order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SomeDialogWindow  extendes DIalogBox..you can do this

```
dialog.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<PopupPanel>() {
public void onClose(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.CloseEvent<PopupPanel> event) {
             yourbutton.setEnabled(true);           

                            };
                        });
```

Comment: It works great. I don't know how I overlooked this handler but anyway thank you :)